# MVC Asp.net Add script to every view with Ajax website

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My whole website is an Ajax website because I have a footer music player.

I would like to add:

```
@using (Html.BeginScriptContext())
{
    Html.AddScriptBlock(
        @<script>
                @if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    <text>
            window.rootQuery = '@Request.Url.Query';
            window.rootAction = '@Url.Action("/")';
            window.absolutePath = '@Request.Url.AbsolutePath';
        </text>
            }
    </script>, 
true);
}
```

To every page without having to go into my 30+ views and manually do it.
I can't just add this to Layout.cshtml because Layout isn't called when you return a partialViewResult which is what my website is doing 90% of the time.
Any way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't have this problem if you didn't mix javascript with server code. It's called *"separation of concerns"* .

Comment: I think you should add the main script to your layout as a function, then call that function in all the 30+ views with different params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be adding this code to a partial view and rendering this partial view to the pages you want to. Still you would manually need to add a line to all the pages. Something like:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyPlugin", Model.PluginData);
```

Hope it helps.